Custom Headers not included in Android POST Method
I am trying to call POST method with Custom Headers in Flutter for both iOS and Android.
For iOS, custom headers are included properly and call was success; but custom headers are mssing in Android and the call was unsuccessful due to missing headers.
Can anyone please help on this?
I am using flutter_inappwebview 6.0.0 (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview), also had tried with webview_flutter 4.8.0 (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#setting-custom-headers-on-post-requests) both web views seem to be resulted in the same behaviour.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
